# Image input for Python Tensorflow model in CoreML

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, coreml, coremltools

I'm implementing a simple image classification model with tensor flow (python).

Here's my image preprocessing:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile USB-C/traan/*.jpeg'): #assuming jpeg
    im=Image.open(filename)
    im = im.resize((150,120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    print(im.size)
    training_images.append(im)
```

And here's my very simple model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(120, 150, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

I want to load this model to CoreML something like this,

```
import coremltools

modelCoreML = coremltools.converters.tensorflow.convert(model, input_feature, output_feature)
modelCoreML.save("Model.mlmodel")
```

But how do I do this where I can input an image, and not a numpy stack? Should I process the image and turn it into the right format in the app itself, then put it in the model? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the `image_input_names` argument to `coremltools.converters.keras.convert()` so that coremltools knows which inputs should be treated as images. This is explained in the [documentation](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.keras.convert.html).